# CPU issue in a cocos2d project -- simple project runs really slow

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

Thanks for your time reading this!

I used Cocos2d and Box2d in my project. The logic of the project is pretty simple. Player just shoots at enemies.If the bullet hits an enemy, the bullet as well as the enemy will be destroyed.If any enemy walks through the screen without getting shot, then the game is over. Part of code is as follows:

```
- (void)birdDone:(ZLBird*) birdToDelete {

CCSprite *sprite = (CCSprite *)birdToDelete;

b2Body *spriteBody = NULL;
for(b2Body *b = world->GetBodyList(); b; b=b->GetNext()) {
    if (b->GetUserData() != NULL) {
        CCSprite *curSprite = (__bridge CCSprite *)b->GetUserData();
        if (sprite == curSprite) {
            spriteBody = b;
            break;
        }
    }
}

if (spriteBody != NULL) {
    world->DestroyBody(spriteBody);
}
[sprite removeFromParentAndCleanup:YES];
sprite = NULL;
}


-(void) update:(ccTime)delta{

SOME CODE HERE

for (b2Body* b = world->GetBodyList(); b; b = b->GetNext())
{
    CCSprite *myActor = (__bridge CCSprite*)b->GetUserData();
    if (b->GetUserData() != NULL)
    {
        //Synchronize the AtlasSprites position and rotation with the corresponding body
        myActor.position = (CGPointMake( b->GetPosition().x * PTM_RATIO, b->GetPosition().y * PTM_RATIO));
        myActor.rotation = (-1 * CC_RADIANS_TO_DEGREES(b->GetAngle()));
    }
}

// goes through all the rocks
for (ZLRock *rockToAct in rocksArr){
    [rockToAct incrementTime];
    if ([rockToAct getExistedTime] >= 400)
    {
        // Remove the rock several seconds after it has been shot
        [self rockDone:rockToAct];
    }
}

// goes through all the elements in BirdsArr
for (ZLBird *birdToAct in birdsArr){
    [birdToAct incrementTime];
    if ([birdToAct getDeadTime] >= 400 || birdToAct.position.x > WIDTH_WINDOW+20)
    {
        // Remove the bird several seconds after it has been dead
        [self birdDone:birdToAct];
    }

    // JUST FOR TEST
    if (birdToAct.position.x > WIDTH_WINDOW && !birdToAct.isDead)
        NSLog(@"YOU LOSSSSSSSS!");
}
```

When I run this project on my iphone, somehow it gets really slow. I checked CPU usage on Instruments, the CPU usage is like 70%.

Why is that? I guess there's no memory leak since I enabled ARC. Is it because I go through several arrays in each frame, and that really makes the device slow down?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Maybe try to use Xcode Instruments to find out, which part of the code takes the most time to run? If you're lucky you will find an obvious bottleneck.

Comment: As with all questions about performance, it would help to mention the amount of data you are dealing with (number of bodies in this case), and give an objective description of what you mean by "slow" . You could also try removing some things to isolate the cause of the slowdown (eg. is it still slow if don't render anything, etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found out the problem!

I didn't remove those objects from array when I remove them from their parent. So the array size keep growing, and finally cause crush.

Thanks for the answers!